# What did I break in my Eclipse formatter?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-formatting, autoformatting, eclipse-formatter

Recently lost a dev machine and I just can't seem to get my formatter back to how it worked before. I've gotten it really close but there's a few things where I just can't figure out what the formatter setting is to fix it!

Before

```
public void method1() {
    MyObject myObject = 
        MyObject
            .builder()
            .param1(param1)
            .param2(param2)
            .param3(param3)
            .build();
}
```

After

```
public void method1() {
    MyObject myObject = MyObject
        .builder()
        .param1(param1)
        .param2(param2)
        .param3(param3)
        .build();
}
```

Before

```
public void method2() {
    mySomewhatLongName.methodName(somewhatLongMethod(myObject.getParam1(),
            myObject.getParam2);
}
```

After

```
public void method2() {
    mySomewhatLongName
            .methodName(somewhatLongMethod(myObject.getParam1(),myObject.getParam2);
}
```

Before

```
public void method3() {
    SomeEnumVariable someLongerObject =
            StringUtils.isNotEmpty(someString) ? SomeEnumVariable.VALUE_1
                    : SomeEnumVariable.VALUE_1;
}
```

After

```
public void method3() {
    SomeEnumVariable someLongerObject = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(someString)
            ? SomeEnumVariable.VALUE_1 : SomeEnumVariable.VALUE_1;
}
```

I know formatting isn't a big deal but my CRs are just all my autoformatter annihilating existing code and I just want to fix this.

Comment: What version of Eclipse? The specifics are a bit different depending upon the version. However, look in Line Wrapping.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset formatting settings by going to project > properties > Java Code Style > Formatter

Enable Project-specific settings, and change your active profile to  `Eclipse [built-in]`

You can also create your own formatting settings, if you want.

Comment: Yeah I had a very well-curated fully custom formatter preferences set... That I should have backed up but didn't.

Comment: You can export you formatting options as a file. please do this so I can open it up for further examination.

Comment: can you post your current config file? It would help examine the problem